# Sorting Cube Surfaces Lambda Syntax Error

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to sort the surfaces of a rotating cube in python and but I'm running into a syntax error using inline Lambda. I've not used Lambda before so I'm struggling here.

```
sorted_faces = sorted(cube_faces, key=lambda face: sum([(cube_points_rotated[i][k] - camera_position[k])**2 for k in range(3)]) for i in face)
```

the error is:

```
sorted_faces = sorted(cube_faces, key=lambda face: sum([(cube_points_rotated[i][k] - camera_position[k])**2 for k in range(3)]) for i in face)
                                  ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you want you lambda function to return? for now, it's not syntactically correct, because of the ` for i in face` at the end. When lambda functions start to be too long, that's a good sign that you should refactor it into it's own function, so that things are more clear for you, and whoever reads your code

Comment: I've refactored it like you said thanks

Answer (score 0):

After expanding the lambda function into it's own function it works flawlessly

```
def face_distance(face):
    distance = 0
    for i in face:
        for k in range(3):
            distance += (cube_points_rotated[i][k] - camera_position[k])**2
    return distance

sorted_faces = sorted(cube_faces, key=face_distance)
```